# How to locate which script is making calls to an external IP?

Tags: php, server, joomla3.0

I am reviewing a website that opens requests to an external address that does not respond and this causes delays in rendering the page.

The only constant so far is the site is making connections to the remote IP `148.251.120.229`:

```
connect(7<TCP:[8935850]>, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("148.251.120.229")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=7<TCP:[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:55186->148.251.120.229:80]>, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 60000^C
```

Furthermore when trying to connect to the remote IP with a 5 seconds timeout all connections failed:

```
for x in {1..10}; do timeout 5 telnet 148.251.120.229 80; done
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
Trying 148.251.120.229...
```

It appears the site times out when trying to connect to the remote IP address, but on occasions, the IP responds faster and the site loads.

I need help locating what php script on the site is making requests to this external address.  How to locate the origin of this application?

Comment: If the connection times out and PHP is set to log errors, those timeout errors will be in your log along with the specific file and line number in which the error occurred.

Comment: I’d simply start with a search for `148.251.120.229` across the whole code base (any decent IDE allows to do that in one way or another, WinSCP or similar can also do it directly on the server.) If it can’t be found hard-coded anywhere, then I’d proceed with a search on the database - if you can identify a specific table and column it occurs in, then use those to find places in the code that might make queries fetching that data.

Comment: but.. if is not a request to an IP and its to an address? Thanks i will try and will update results

Comment: [root@hera ~]# grep -rnw '/home/userfolder/' -e "148.251.120.229"
Nothing found...

Answer (score 1):

you can set in php.ini file:

allow_url_fopen = Off

and block outgoing connections to an URL adresses.

Our customer had the same problem with this IP and it works.